# Predictive model from ordinal panel data

Tags: r, repeated-measures, predictive-models, ordinal-data, panel-data

Here's a hypothetical problem analogous to one that I am having trouble with:

Prostate cancer biopsies are scored according to Gleason pattern (0-10). The scale is ordinal. Over 7 warrants surgery.

Patients at risk for prostate cancer were followed with serial biopsies at irregular intervals. Our data consists of a series of biopsies (date and result) for many patients (i.e. 1000 results for 100 patients), along with patient characteristics that may influence risk like sex, birthdate (i.e. age), race etc.

What models could be estimated with this data to predict the probability of Gleason > 7 at next biopsy? Or if simpler, what model could predict Gleason score at next biopsy? Intuitively it should incorporate the last biopsy results, time since last biopsy, and the other patient characteristics.

I generally use R. Relevant papers, packages, etc. would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.